# find twice optimal cost of locations in 2d space efficiently

Tags: c, algorithm, math, geometry

I have a 2d grid of say 100 by 100 dimensions. Each point (x,y) in the grid has an associated cost and it is **monotonically non-decreasing** thoroughout the space. The cost associated is not known in advance.

I cant afford to find the cost of all locations. So what I do is, find cost of top most location(100,100). Call it cost C. Then identify **iso-cost contours** on this 2d grid for a **carefully chosen** set of cost values. Let C be the cost location (100,100). The cost for contours has been carefully chosen in such a way that, last contour(contour k) will be of cost C(maximum cost in the grid), contour k-1 will be of cost C/2, contour k-2 will be of cost C/4 like that in Geometric series.  Iso cost contours are shown in Black colour curves. They are identified by first locating a seed on the left/top edge and then exploring along its neighbourhood.

Now for any location (x,y) on the contour, the nearest contour's cost will give an **approximate value** for cost of location (x,y). That is we get a cost value which is less than **twice the actual cost** of location (x,y). Each location (x,y) on a contour covers the region in its third quadrant. For example, the location M is covered by contour with cost C/8.
[image: contour diagram]
So for any given location (x,y) i can say what is the cost by seeing who is the nearest contour above it and its cost. This gives a cost which is closest but not the exact cost of the location (x,y) which is enough for my case. But it requires me to 
a) find complete isocost contours for C, C/2, C/4 upto Cmin.
b) store all the above mentioned iso-contour locations, which is 100 locations per contour.

How to have **very minimum number of points** in the space to be **explored and stored**, and still achieve this property of twice optimal cost?

Note: Number of locations costed needs to be brought down. currently I am costing all isocost contour locations. Resolution of 100 by 100 is for explaining the problem. Actual resolutions are very higher.

Comment: @chux could you elaborate more?

Comment: Is it an issue of temporary storage, memory usage, etc.  What are you attempting to achieve by storing the minimum number of points here?  We can use compression with deltas to turn your points into a smaller footprint.  Also, accuracy?  If you don't need 100% accuracy, you could use a least-squared equation based solution where you store the coefficiences of the iso-cost equation.  This requries all the points up front, but stores less.  Just looking for a bit more clarification.

Comment: @CRM  Sorry - I'll need to ponder it more.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Though i framed it that way, memory is not the only issue..if there is less number of points enough to cover the entire space without increasing cost of any location by more than twice its actual cost, I would not find complete isocost contour itself..I have edited the question now.

Comment: Perhaps a bit of source also might help.  In my head, I'm thinking of a Radix type sort on your costs where you loop through your data once, sorting by cost, and then finding all your values becomes much easier, but I'm not 100% certain still of what you are trying to minimize and why.  You say you store 100x100 points - this is only 10k points.  How many points in the original data are you having to sort through?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I dont have cost values of 10k points upfront. It is not possible to compute cost of 10k points. that is why I am trying these methods. Grid is just a virtual grid.

Comment: Ok, the cost calculation is extemely expensive?  BTW, I don't know if I am the person who will ultimately be able to help you, but I'm hoping my questions will make it clearer for others that are reading.

Comment: As far as i understand `monotonically non-decreasing` can lead to some kind of a bounding box principle : if x0<x<x1 and y0<y<y1 then C(x0,y0)<=C(x,y)<=C(x1,y1). So the problem boils down to covering space with boxes such that C(x0,y0)<=C(x1,y1)<=2C(x0,y0). To approximate the cost, find the box in which x,y is ! Building a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) seems the right way to go. The cell must be divided until the corner of the cell is such that `C(x1,y1)<=2C(x0,y0)`. To optimize, the cut of a cell could be performed at a well chosen location (not in the middle).

Comment: You could scan the left and top edges of the grid to find one end of each isocost line, and then trace each one by examining nearby points, to the right and/or below.  I guess that way you probably end up examining about 200 + 2.5 * `P` points, where `P` is the total number of points on all contours.

Comment: You say "currently I am costing all isocost contour locations", but IIUC, *you don't know* where the isocost lines actually lie until you've costed some locations...  So which locations are you actually costing to determine the isocost contour lines?

Comment: Further to @JohnBollinger's suggestion, you should always test 2 out of the 3 neighbours (right, down and down+right).  Test DR first: if this cost is higher than the target cost for this isocost line, you only need to test D, and take whichever of the 2 is closer to the target; if it's lower, you only need to test R.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am doing what you have mentioned only for tracing contours for C, C/2, C/4 etc. As you said, now I will have to trace entire contour for C, C/2 etc. Should I do that?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I am finding isocost contours for C, C/2, C/4 by the same idea as John Bollinger mentioned in his comment. Starting with a seed on the left/top boundary then growing it along its neighbourhood. But this requires costing an entire contour for C, C/2, C/4 etc. Can I cost fewer locations than finding complete isocost contours for C, C/2 etc and still bound all locations cost by twice its cost?

Comment: @CRM, If you need to know where the contours are, and you don't have a functional form for them, then I don't see any alternative to tracing them out.  You could possibly sample a coarser grid (maybe every 4th x value, for example) and interpolate, but I think you'll end up costing about the same number of points that way, because on average you'll need to examine more points at each x you consider.

Comment: @JohnBollinger When tracing a contour for say C/2, can I assume that the contour always starts at a boundary and ends at a boundary. Can it be possible that a contour never touches the boundary in a space like this.

Comment: @CRM, Given that the cost is monotonically non-decreasing in both x and y, every path from (0, 0) to (100, 100) crosses every contour for costs between C(0,0) and C(100,100).  Paths that do not backtrack in x or y cross every such contour exactly once.  In particular, the path consisting of the union of the left and top edges has this property.  Along some paths there may be multiple points whose cost is exactly the contour cost, but those must be contiguous.

Comment: @CRM, that does suggest a possible refinement: you could scan for each contour along the main diagonal, and then trace in both directions.  That would save you about 100 cost computations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lower bound for the worst case number of locations you need to test that is not too far from the upper bound you get by locating the isocost contours.

Imagine that you know every value except the one at *:

```
.  2  .
1  *  2
.  1  .
```

This value could be 1 or 2. (If that ambiguity is acceptable then you could replace the 2 with 2.001.) So, you need to sample it. There is no way you can determine the value from the costs at other sites.

Let k = log_2(cost(n,n)/cost(1,1)). You can construct a cost function so that at almost nk sites (about k(n-k/2)), you can't determine the cost within a factor of 2 without sampling that site. I'll illustrate an example where k=3.

```
      8 8 8 8 8 8
    4 * 8 8 8 8 8
  2 * 4 * 8 8 8 8
1 * 2 * 4 * 8 8 8
1 1 * 2 * 4 * 8 8
1 1 1 * 2 * 4 * 8
1 1 1 1 * 2 * 4
1 1 1 1 1 * 2 
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

So, the number of sites you need to test is theta(nk) for n>>k. You might be able to do much better on average if you have a probabilistic model for the cost function, and k is small compared with n.

Comment: I am not clear. If we identify isocost contours for C, C/2, C/4 etc as shown in the image then any location cost can be approximated within twice its cost by the bounding contour right?

Comment: @CRM: Yes, that algorithm works. My answer shows that you can't do much better in the worst case, that there are cost functions that require you to evaluate the cost function in about as many places (Theta(nk), when n>>k) as it takes to find the isocost contours.

Comment: In your first example, the value at * is surely greater than or equal to 1 and it is less than or equal to 2. We can find its value within twice the actual value

Comment: As I said, it's ambiguous whether being off by exactly a factor of two counts as within twice the value or not. So, I explicitly stated that in case being off by exactly a factor of 2 was acceptable, that you could replace the 2 with 2.001. This would mean that you can't tell the value of the * within a factor of 2.001. Is this clear enough?

Comment: Yeah I got it. It seems like there is no better way to get cost of any location in the space within twice optimal cost without finding all locations of isocost contours for C, C/2, C/4 etc. It would be helpful if it can be proved mathematically.

Comment: That is what my answer proves, that up to a constant factor, there if no better way.

Answer (score -1):

Even though it's not clear to me what you mean "monotonically non-decreasing  thoroughout the space", I understand that this is a constrained minimization of a two variables function.

If you means that the cost is monotonically non-decreasing both in the x and in the y directions. That is:

cost(x1, y) <= cost(x2, y) for any x1 < x2 and any y

and

cost(x, y1) <= cost(x, y1) for any y1 < y2 and any x

If this is the case, the solution is in (1,1).

If my assumption about the constraints is not correct, anyway from the plot it looks like the solution lies on the border. In this case you don't need to use any complex algorithm for constrained minimization: just explore the border starting from (1,1) in the two directions increasing x and increasing y. This move from n^2 problem to a n problem.

Comment: S/he's not looking to find the point that minimises or maximises the cost function, but to choose a subset of the points to measure such that it is then possible to answer a query on *any* point with an approximate cost that is guaranteed to be at most twice the true value.